# A kind of revenge?

Tags: support, etiquette, down-votes, serial-voting

I just saw some downvoting activity on many questions I answered (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43608/arbautjc?tab=reputation)), not long after I answered [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340709/convergency-of-the-functions-nf-n-converge-to-f-in-l-1#comment733772_340709).
Is there anything I can do ?

**EDIT** Ok, so MSE has correctly reversed thing during night, but things seem to continue this morning ([reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43608/arbautjc?tab=reputation)). But of course, I have no more proof than yesterday. And with the added benefit that moderate downvoting has more chances to look normal (after all, somebody may perfectly well dislike these two posts). Nice.

Comment: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Quite reassuring to see there are ways to solve problems, if they persist.

Comment: I just looked at you solution for the indefinite integral.  It certainly was OK, nobody should be downvoting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Martin's link says everything that needs to be said. Basically: if someone is really targeting you for serial down-voting, the system has ways of finding it out and automatically refund you reputation. So just take a deep breath and wait a bit. If by tomorrow this time the situation has not been resolved automatically, flag a moderator and we'll look into it.

Comment: Deep breaths are good! But why not just do something about it now? I am of course not a moderator, but wouldn't a temporary suspension be in order to make sure that the user doesn't continue. Deep breath Deep breath - becoming hyperoxic.

Comment: Suspensions are heavy punishments. Whenever possible we try to give offending users -- especially new ones -- a warning first. This is especially the case where the "damage" caused is easily reversible and less tangible. So yes, in some cases it is good to step in and stop the activity in its tracks; and in some cases it is not necessary.

Comment: @Thomas, if I understand correctly the moderators cannot see who serial voted, until the script has identified the issue and reversed the problem. An immediate suspension would mean that you pin the fault on someone who may not be guilty.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Ok, I see. That makes sense if it isn't clear who actually did the serial downvoting.

Comment: @Thomas: If waiting a single day will result in hard evidence, I prefer the moderators to wait, rather than using their judgement and possibly circumstantial evidence.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I agree. I would not want to be "punished" for something I didn't do because of an overeagerness to react fast. But I guess that I would also still say that if hard evidence was available earlier, then in my opinion action earlier is better.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm not eagerly asking for punishment. Actually it's the first time it happens to me on SE, and I wanted to know the options. At least I know I'm not alone in case things go wrong. Let's wait and see.

Comment: Agreed with Asaf that I don't know for sure - though it's the first time I downvote anybody + this guy downvote score is quite high, so I'd say chances are high. But probability is not proof, we know that in maths :-) Anyway, fever may fall by itself.